# Is it possible to find out position of a unit in project's uses clause?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have two units (SuperPuper.pas and SuperPuper777.pas) in a project (.exe or .dll)

Is it possible to find out at runtime from my code in `SuperPuper777.pas` that

1. `SuperPuper.pas` is listed in project's `uses` clause;
2. `SuperPuper.pas` is first unit in project's `uses` clause.

---

The question was heavily edited. I guess that it's practical purpose is to find out if `ShareMem.pas` unit was declared in right position in project's `uses` clause.

Comment: I'm sorry, Gu, but your question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Terrible description any little bit was before...

Comment: The description is still quite poor.

Comment: I do not know how still to tell. It is necessary to receive sequence of list USES in DPR::

Comment: 1. It is necessary in <necessary> the module need the list: "Forms, SuperPuper, SuperPuper777, Unit" in strict sequence in DPR
2. If in DPR there is no module - to receive the list all ok since the part of modules is connected through "ways of a fast call" (path)

P.S. At you always do "down like" for people "2 grade"?
Your nation and is not present 300 years, and democracy in all world bear.

Comment: As heaven is my witness, Gu, I'm trying to understand you, but it's just not happening.

Comment: Adding Delhi XE2 tag. Gu uses Delphi XE2, according to his initial header. This is a relevant input.

Comment: @Gu: Please confirm, does the extensive edit of Serg convey what you mean to say?

Comment: Based on your previous question you are trying to write a DLL with string parameters that can be accessed from languages other than Delphi. Sharemem will not help. Do not use string. Use PChar or Widestrimg.

Comment: Please, please, cut it out. It has been named a **language barrier** for purpose. By the way, A is for America.

Comment: @user53  to whom is that comment addressed?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all units linked to the executable (i.e. at runtime) from the resources. There is a resource named `PACKAGEINFO` which contains a list of all units. You can find some reverse information [from here](http://www.heaventools.com/forum/index.php?topic=51.0). Perhaps you can get this information from enhanced RTTI (available since Delphi 2010).

About how to detect that an unit is first in the .dpr uses clause, I do not see any way of doing it at runtime easily. The list in `PACKAGEINFO` is not in this order. You can do that at compile time, by parsing the .dpr content and checking its uses clause.

The only way I see to guess which unit was first set is to use a global variable in a common unit:

```
 var LatestUnitSet: (oneUnit, anotherUnit);
```

Then in the initialization section of each unit:

```
initialization
  LatestUnitSet := OneUnit;
...


initialization
  LatestUnitSet := anotherUnit;
...
```

Then check for `LatestUnitSet` to see which one was initialized the latest.

Comment: How about implementing registration mechanism with a project wide registry singleton and register every unit in its initialization clause ?

Comment: @menjaraz, so you're suggesting modifying the entire VCL source folders to add an initialization unit? Because the OP is asking about `ShareMem`, which is part of the RTL. The other problem with that is that the initialization causes the unit to be linked in whether it's actually needed or not, which adds a lot of unnecessary code to your app and increases the executable size.

Comment: @Ken White: It's not all my intent, it would silly to touch the VCL. According to the initial post, my understanding of the problem is this: Given 2 custom units whose source codes are available, how to probe in runtime from statement within the other unit the fact that the first one is linked to the project in the right order (1st rank in the project uses clause).

Comment: What might be a "VCL source folders"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce the correct declaration of a unit in a project's `uses` clause I would add a pre-build event to run a regex based Perl/Python/Ruby script. The script would do a simple regex based check of the .dpr file and return an error if it was not as intended. Not fool-proof, but probably the best balance of utility for a small amount of effort.

I realise that your question asks for runtime detection but this is a compile time property and so best attacked at compile time.